# what does "Save the hammer for the man" mean in this context?

Tags: phrase-meaning, lyrics

This is part of the lyrics of the song "Save the Hammer for the Man," by Tom Morello (& Ben Harper):

> I hurt the gentlest souls, I robbed my wife and son
>   I turned my back on troubles, troubles I'd begun
>   I cut a swath of pain and loss in the hallways of my home
>   In the quiet of my room I know the things I've done
>   Save the hammer for the man, save the hammer for the man
>   It's the calling of the wretched
>   It's the rising of the damned
>   Save the hammer for the man
>
> <sub>Tom Morello & Ben Harper</sub>

What does the phrase "Save the hammer for the man" mean in this context?

Comment: Thank you for introducing me to a hauntingly beautiful new song and songwriter.

Comment: I'm glad you liked the song and the songwriter!  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Put the hammer down" is to react with force

["The Man"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man) is also slang for the establishment/police

If you Google ***What does save the hammer for the man mean***

you would find

[Tom Morello on solo album, politics and racism](http://edition.cnn.com/2011/09/28/showbiz/music/tom-morello-album/)

> The two musicians have an easy friendship. For years, they've supported each other's charitable endeavors and activist causes -- which inadvertently led to their first duet, the gospel-tinged "Save the Hammer for the Man." It's a track on "World Wide Rebel Songs," Morello's fourth record under the guise of his Nightwatchman alter ego.
>   "We were playing a show in Chicago for some union issue, and some of the other musicians on the bill were grousing about not getting paid," Morello says. "One of the other musicians canceled the show because he had to return to his vineyard. We were on the phone kind of moaning about this, and Ben said, 'Tom, you let me know if you want me to put the hammer down.' And I said, 'Ben, save the hammer for the man.' And we're like, 'Hold on. One day, that must be a song!' "

Comment: ...ops, I just realized that I Googled a wrong prashe, that's why I did not find anything .... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think *save the hammer for the man* means that the people/ citizens are the ones to decide their own justice, fate, fighting for their country and they should protest against corruption/ injustice/ fascism against Government. Let the (majority) that is the people of a country to decide for the betterment of their country instead of watching it getting destroyed by their own corrupted government. The singer realised that he too is a sinner and is asking for redemption by fighting for justice and fairness. He is sharing 'words of freedom' to make a change in the world, to wake the mass up and to stand up for their rights and beliefs.

Answer (score 0):

Francesca--

I think that there are several things going on here. First, this verse is an expression of regret over misplaced anger. It also establishes the reason for the exile described in the middle of the song. Finally, it lends depth to the finish -- there's a sense of redemption to lyrics that might other come across as didactic. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but here's my take; talking about the hammer of a gun, meaning for the down and out to save it for those responsible for their, and the world's, troubles, which would be those in power. Using it in this way may lead to resolution, to freedom (though perhaps not their own), to liberation, as opposed to using it against another who isn't the real source of the problem, at best only misperceived as such, and at worse just someone through which a temporary fix may be achieved (think someone so down and out they rob a liquor store in an attempt to provide the solution of feeding their hungry kids when the clerk actually shares an enemy)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It meas to save violence for the government.  Or don't bitch and moan for not being paid for doing what you love.